# Javascript Input Event Fire Twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, dom-events

I want to upload an Excel file through the browser and I am showing this file. However sometimes there is an error and I need to change some columns in the Excel file and I want to upload the same file. The event is firing just one time because filename is the same. How can I solve this problem? I want to upload the same file and I want the event to fire twice.

```
document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('input', handleFileSelect, false);

var handleFileSelect = function(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
  var xl2json = new ExcelToJSON();
  xl2json.parseExcel(files[0]);
  console.log(evt)
};
```

```html
<input id="upload" type=file  name="files[]">
```

I tried

```
$("#upload").unbind("input").bind("input",handleFileSelect)
```

and

```
document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false)
```

Comment: We can't really help you without seeing much more of your logic; the logic in `handleFileSelect()` at the very least. Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *within the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added my code

Comment: I tried   $("#upload").unbind("input").bind("input",handleFileSelect) and document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking. How are you amending the Excel file that's uploaded? The filename being the same in two file controls will not stop the file being uploaded, it's all in how you deal with the original file and its amendment. Why is the event firing twice relevant?

Comment: Actually I am creating table using tabulator and ı am controlling column name. If there is an error in column name, showed this column is red and give an error. So user return the Excel file and change column name and upload same file. But he cant upload. For example Last column name is total price. But there is an total money. User is  changing column name and upload file. But he cant

Comment: True excel file should be  (column name) Date | Total Amount. But user has (column name) Date | Total Money. So he must change second column name and upload. but file is the same. So ı need upload same file second time. But ı cant

Answer (score 2):

You should use the **onChange** event.

```
var el = document.getElementById('upload');
el.onchange = function() {
  // your code...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I added this code in my function

```
 evt.target.value = null;
```